# Best ARIMA Model

Tags: self-study, arima, model-selection, group-differences

What ARIMA model would be the best fit for the data provided?:

```
    Log Data
    4.80925
    4.79486
    5.10405
    4.99157
    5.14573
    5.43213
    4.82344
    5.04939
    5.38104
    5.17092
    4.96136
    5.27926
    5.43213
    5.45860
    5.76751
    5.48801
    5.02090
    5.86406
    5.47708
    5.45486
    6.15547
    5.67275
    5.65144
    5.67575
    5.66062
    5.75371
    6.03513
    5.66367
    5.41669
    6.06609
    5.43596
    5.69361
    5.87396
    5.90787
    5.75926
    5.88377
    5.52010
    6.12144
    6.40864
    6.05382
    6.20267
    6.18658
    6.20267
    6.12910
    6.29733
    6.34150
    6.41869
    6.67444
    5.72268
    6.56957
    7.05300
    6.72091
    6.76329
    7.18416
    6.87882
    6.70602
    6.98400
    6.92120
    6.89404
    7.14209
    6.90552
    7.25532
    7.44422
    7.27493
    7.39001
    7.65955
    6.82796
    6.75720
    7.40237
    7.00886
    7.05753
    6.94173
    6.86795
    7.10179
    7.30834
    6.89935
    6.93322
    7.24412
    6.70709
    6.76329
    7.34465
    6.91077
    6.86795
    7.35758
    6.97093
    7.00965
    7.78806
    7.32001
    7.53711
    7.49125
    7.17615
    7.44166
    7.57332
    7.70517
    7.83524
    8.17037
    7.34352
    7.71693
    7.98283
    7.80891
    7.84455
    8.05212
    7.79854
    7.65416
    8.25674
    7.95186
    8.05963
    8.28055
    8.02125
    8.28344
    8.42345
    8.20280
    8.25879
    8.52682
    8.00325
    7.89247
    8.62445
    8.20568
    7.79782
    8.17482
    7.70319
    8.10535
    8.36399
    8.07665
    8.06872
    8.17260
    7.68241
    7.33726
    8.14756
    7.76267
```

We have tried many combinations but the p-values of the residuals are too low (not white noise). We tried ARIMA (2,1,0)(1,0,0), (0,1,1)(1,0,0) and (0,1,1)(1,0,1) none of them show promising p-values in chi-square test.

Comment: What have you tried, what have you looked into? As it stands now, your question seems to be asking for someone to do the analysis for you. If you show a little bit of effort, I'm sure people would be happy to help.

Comment: We have tried many combinations but the p-values of the residuals are too low (not white noise). We tried ARIMA (2,1,0)(1,0,0), (0,1,1)(1,0,0) and (0,1,1)(1,0,1) none of them show promising p-values in chi-square test.

Comment: 12 was the seasonal differences we used

Comment: Could you please edit your question to reflect what you've tried so far, and the reasons why it won't work? (in other words, could you edit your question to add what you just said, instead of leaving those in comments?)

Comment: Run arima.auto in R, it'll give you "best" arima.

Comment: @Aksakal: Think you mean `auto.arima` from the `forecast` package.

Comment: @Scortchi, yes. With the description that is given it's the only thing to advise.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Can't see a reason to close this question that feels quite right, and I'm curious about ARIMA, so I thought I'd give @Aksakal's suggestion a whirl.</sup> FWIW, here's the result of `summary(auto.arima(YourDataGoesHere)` in [r](/questions/tagged/r):

```
Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2   drift
      -0.6863  -0.6220  0.0226
s.e.   0.0690   0.0696  0.0098

sigma^2 estimated as 0.06492:  log likelihood=-7.25
AIC=22.5   AICc=22.83   BIC=33.94

Training set error measures:
                       ME     RMSE       MAE         MPE     MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set 0.0007415827 0.253817 0.1984549 -0.04473738 2.987506 0.6909561 0.03085935
```

It's picking a (2,1,0) model. Just for the love of plots, `plot(forecast(autoarima(YourDataGoesHere)))`:

> [image]

Not sure how far out you really want to forecast, but setting *p* values aside, this seems much better than nothing. Enter an argument for `h` in `forecast` if you want to extend the forecast further.

Kudos to [Rob Hyndman](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/159/rob-hyndman) for authoring `forecast`! I'm already a fan.

Comment: What about the outliers?  If you ignore outliers, then the model and forecast will be skewed.  Refer to the work done by Tsay www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf  -  .799  at        49
                         -  .669  at       128
                         -  .365  at        67
                         -  .446  at        97
                         -  .470  at        68
                         -  .449  at       121
                         -  .477  at        17

Comment: The forecasts are skewed low by the outlier at period 128